# Removing black edge artifacts from a transparent image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a set of transparent PNG images with black artifacts around the edges, like this:

[image: Example image]

I'm looking for a way to clean up the borders automatically. I tried simply masking out pixels under a certain RGB value, but the images themselves can also contain black pixels, and those then get filtered out. I'm using Python3 and opencv3/PIL.

My question is: **How can I get rid of the black edges, while preserving black pixels that are not part of an edge?**

EDIT: As usr2564301 pointed out below, very few (if any) of the edge pixels are pure black. I still need to remove them, so I'd want to use some threshold value and **remove pixels that are neighbors to a transparent pixel and are either:**

- **Darker than the *threshold*,** or
- **Darker by at least *threshold* than any neighboring non-transparent pixel.**

Comment: The edges are not all black, only some pixels are. *Very*, *very* few, actually. Clicking here and there I can't even find *one*. What do you want to happen with pixels on the border that are not black, dark, or even medium – but still 'darker than a random adjecent pixel'?

Comment: Good catch! In that case, I guess it'd make sense to consider some threshold value, and remove pixels that 1) border a transparent pixel, and 2) are at least `threshold` darker than any of the surrounding non-transparent pixels, or at least `threshold` lighter than pure black.

Comment: Generally, you can't get the real slash in binary mode.

Comment: use the transparency channel to find all the object pixels (create a mask from it). Then erode that mask or remove all the mask points where there are sharp color changes at the border with a pixel value near black.

Comment: How would I find the color changes? That's one thing I couldn't find an explanation on how to do, and iterating over all pixels (and then checking four or more neighbors) seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Try taking the alpha channel and eroding it by a couple of pixels. I am illustrating the technique with **ImageMagick** because that's easier, but you can do the same thing with **OpenCV**:

```
convert pinkboythingwithcathead.png \( +clone -alpha extract -morphology erode disk:2 \) -compose copy-alpha -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: That's a good idea, but it removes more than just the absolute edge pixels, doesn't it?

Comment: Oh, I see that is what Micka was suggesting in the comments - more or less.

Comment: It's more of a conceptual answer - I am not sure what it is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 2):

You can antialias the edges of the alpha channel in ImageMagick as follows:

Input:

[image]

```
convert image.png -channel a -blur 0x2 -level 50x100% +channel result.png
```

[image]

Adjust the 2 using smaller values than 2 if thinner black border and larger than 2 if broader black borders.